# How do I conditionally add an ASP.NET Core 7 Controller?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I am working on a multi-tenant and multi-cluster application. The same application is deployed on multiple clusters and each cluster serves different tenants. Each different cluster is aware of which tenants it is serving via some values in `appsettings.json`.

I need to publish a specific Controller's endpoints only for a specific tenant. Actually it would be enough to publish it only inside the cluster that's serving the specific tenant.
To be more specific:

- cluster *C1* is serving tenant *T1* and *T2*
- cluster *C2* is serving tenant *T3* and *T4*
- I need the Controller to be published only for cluster *C2* and not for *C1*

I could check inside the routes which tenant is executing the request and return a 404 if it's not the right one, but I think excluding the endpoint via dependency injection or some other mechanisms would be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: Do you want the controller to perform different operations for different tenants? Maybe you can consider using [ActionFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filters.actionfilterattribute?view=aspnetcore-7.0). Here is the [reference link](https://github.com/anuraj/AspNetCoreSamples/tree/master/Multitenancy).

Comment: No, I'd like simply for the endpoint to be there for a certain tenant, while not being published at all for other tenants.